# How can I change the color of a button and display text based on a form submission? (JavaScript/HTML beginner question)

Tags: javascript, html

Javascript beginner mistakes(?). Behavior expected seems to be buggy

I'm trying to create a simple website with a form submission that will make the submit button green if the answer is right and red otherwise. there should also be a text that appears below as "Correct!" or "Wrong"

Here is the code

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach(function(button) {
    button.addEventListener('click', function() {
      document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach(function(btn) {
        btn.style.backgroundColor = '';
      });

      //To get the selected answer
      let selected_answer = button.textContent;

      //Check if answer is correct
      if (selected_answer == 'Korean') {

        button.style.backgroundColor = 'green';

        //Add result as text
        document.querySelector('p').innerHTML = 'Correct';
      } else {
        //if answer is wrong
        button.style.backgroundColor = 'red';

        document.querySelector('p').innerHTML = 'Wrong';
      }
    });
  });
});


document.querySelector('#submit').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  let answer = document.querySelector('#text').value.toLowerCase();
  let button1 = document.querySelector('#submit');

  if (answer === 'latin') {

    button1.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
    document.querySelector('#p2').innerHTML = 'Correct!';
  } else {

    button1.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    document.querySelector('#p2').innerHTML = 'Wrong!';
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <h1>Trivia!</h1>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="section">
    <h2>Part 1: Multiple Choice </h2>
    <hr>
    <h3>Which one of these languages are not spoken in Europe?</h3>

    <button type="button">French</button>
    <button type="button">Italian</button>
    <button type="button">Korean</button>
    <button type="button">Spanish</button>

    <p></p>

  </div>

  <div class="section">
    <h2>Part 2: Free Response</h2>
    <hr>
    <h3>Which language did French, Italian, Spanish and Portuguese cam from?</h3>
    <form>
      <input type="text" id="text">
      <button type="submit" id="submit">Check Answer</button>
    </form>
    <p id="p2"></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Once i run it and answer it correctly the text below will say "CORRECT" however

The submit button will turn red and Part 1 will have a result "Wrong"

Comment: You are assigning the first event handler to all buttons - including the submit button.

Comment: you should not use `innerHTML`  as it is slow (reparse of DOM) and open to security risks (XSS injections). You also should make sue of CSS class and apply them with `classList` instead of using the `style` attirbute

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to add the second event listener for the submit button as it already has event listener in the first function. You just need to add condition that checks if the button's id is submit and if it is it'll fire the code for Part 2 check. Otherwise it will fire the Part 1 check code. The 2 event listeners messed up your code.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach(function(button) {
    button.addEventListener('click', function() {
        document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach(function(btn) {
            btn.style.backgroundColor = '';
        });

        if (button.id === "submit") {
            event.preventDefault();

            let answer = document.querySelector('#text').value.toLowerCase();
            let button1 = document.querySelector('#submit');

            if (answer === 'latin') {

                button1.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
                document.querySelector('#p2').innerHTML = 'Correct!';
            } else {

                button1.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
                document.querySelector('#p2').innerHTML = 'Wrong!';
            }
        } else {
            //To get the selected answer
            let selected_answer = button.textContent;

            //Check if answer is correct
            if (selected_answer == 'Korean') {

                button.style.backgroundColor = 'green';

                //Add result as text
                document.querySelector('p').innerHTML = 'Correct';
            } else {
                //if answer is wrong
                button.style.backgroundColor = 'red';

                document.querySelector('p').innerHTML = 'Wrong';
            }
        }
    });
});
});
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <h1>Trivia!</h1>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="section">
    <h2>Part 1: Multiple Choice </h2>
    <hr>
    <h3>Which one of these languages are not spoken in Europe?</h3>

    <button type="button">French</button>
    <button type="button">Italian</button>
    <button type="button">Korean</button>
    <button type="button">Spanish</button>

    <p></p>

  </div>

  <div class="section">
    <h2>Part 2: Free Response</h2>
    <hr>
    <h3>Which language did French, Italian, Spanish and Portuguese cam from?</h3>
    <form>
      <input type="text" id="text">
      <button type="submit" id="submit">Check Answer</button>
    </form>
    <p id="p2"></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
const ansBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.ansBtn');
const statusText = document.querySelector('#p2');
const submitBtn = document.querySelector('#submit');
let selected_answer = undefined;
let selectedBtn = undefined;
let ansValid = {isValid: false}


ansBtns.forEach((btn) => {
    btn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        ansBtns.forEach((item) => item.style.backgroundColor = '');
        selected_answer = e.target.textContent;
        selectedBtn = e.target;
        if (selected_answer == 'Korean') {
            selectedBtn.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
            ansValid.isValid = true;
            statusText.textContent = 'Correct';
            return;
        }
        selectedBtn.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
        statusText.textContent = 'Wrong';
        ansValid.isValid = false;
    });
});

submitBtn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (ansValid.isValid) {
        statusText.textContent = 'Correct';
        return;
    };
    statusText.textContent = 'Wrong';
    
});
```

});

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You added events to all off the buttons as someone already said that . Just add a class name to buttons with answers for example "class = buttonAnwser" and than use forEach loop to set events on those buttons and everything will work fine and also you dont really need to use nesting , that just add complication in my opinion ... The problem you had is that you assigned events to all buttons including button with id submit so when you click on check answer it fill fire the if block wich is true so its going to set color and text you defined in that if block , and after than its going to go to see if else block is true wich in your case is also true and it will set backgroundColor to red and text to wrong ...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).